$Ad\circ\exp=\exp\circ ad$ and $e^{i(\theta/2)\hat{n}\cdot\sigma}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)\hat{n}\cdot\sigma}=e^{\theta\hat{n}\cdot J}\sigma$
This question is inspired by my recent question How to prove $e^{+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)} = e^{\theta \hat{n}\cdot J}\sigma$? with answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/819562/128186 and chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153836/discussion-between-jagerber48-and-lpz.
We have one formula
$$
\tag{1}
U^{\dagger}(R)\sigma U(R) = e^{+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot J)} = e^{\theta (\hat{n}\cdot J)} \sigma = R\sigma
$$
Where $\sigma$ is a vector of the Pauli matrices (generators of $SU(2)$) and $J$ is a vector of the anti-symmetric generators of $SO(3)$.
There is another deeper formula involving Lie groups and Lie algebras:
$$
\tag{2}
\text{Ad}\circ \exp = \exp \circ \text{ad}
$$
I am trying to understand the relationship between $(1)$ and $(2)$. Can $(2)$ be used to straightforwardly prove/derive $(1)$? I see the ingredients being something like

$(2)$ holds generically for Lie groups/algebras and
$\mathfrak{su(2)}$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$
so somehow we can derive $(1)$ from $(2)$.

I'm very tempted to write
$$
e^{+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)} =  \text{Ad}(\exp(-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)))(\sigma)
$$
Then, using $(2)$, I'd want to equate this too
\begin{align*}
\exp(\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)))(\sigma)
\end{align*}
but then I need to somehow relate this expression to
$$
e^{\theta(\hat{n}\cdot J)}\sigma
$$
and this step I do not know how to do. I suspect/wonder if it is related to the representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ by $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

A few further steps:
I wish I could show
$$
\exp(\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma))) \stackrel{?}{=} \exp(\theta \hat{n}\cdot J)
$$
Or, we would like to show
$$
\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma)) \stackrel{?}{=} \theta \hat{n}\cdot J
$$
Because $\text{ad}$ is linear we have
$$
\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma)) = i(\theta/2)\text{ad}(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma)
$$
So it seems if we could show
$$
\text{ad}(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma) = -2 i \hat{n}\cdot J
$$
that we would about have the answer.

The first title formula (2) is essentially Hadamard's formula https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646480/2451

Perhaps what you are looking for is provided in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff_formula]

Yes, equation (2) basically is the Hadamard's or Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. The question is asking how to use (2) to prove (1).

The original question is really almost there. The answer is that we can almost prove $(1)$ directly from $(2)$. All we need in addition is a few facts about the pauli matrices $\sigma$ and the rotation generators $J$.
$$
\newcommand{\ad}{\text{ad}}
\newcommand{\Ad}{\text{Ad}}
$$
We seek to prove
$$
\tag{1}
e^{+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)} = e^{\theta (\hat{n}\cdot J)}\sigma
$$
using
$$
\tag{2}
\Ad\circ \exp = \exp \circ \ad.
$$
Note that
$$
\Ad(X)(Y) = XYX^{\dagger}\\
\ad(x)(y) = [x, y].
$$
We can write
$$
e^{+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)} = \Ad(\exp(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma))(\sigma).
$$
Using $(2)$, we then equate this to
$$
\exp(\ad(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)))(\sigma)
$$
By linearity of $\ad$ we can write this as
$$
\exp(+i(\theta/2)\ad(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma))(\sigma).
$$
We would like this to be equal to the RHS of $(1)$:
$$
\exp(\theta (\hat{n}\cdot J))\sigma.
$$
This equality would hold if
$$
\ad(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)(\sigma) \stackrel{?}=-2i (\hat{n}\cdot J)\sigma
$$
We will now prove this.
\begin{align*}
(\ad(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)(\sigma))_j =& \ad(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)(\sigma_j)\\
=& [\hat{n} \cdot \sigma, \sigma_j]\\
=& [n_i \sigma_i, \sigma_j]\\
=& n_i[\sigma_i, \sigma_j]\\
=& n_i 2i \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k\\
=& -2i n_i (J_i)_{jk} \sigma_k\\
=& -2i n_i (J_i \sigma)_j\\
=& -2i (n_iJ_i \sigma)_j\\
=& -2i ((\hat{n}\cdot J)\sigma)_j\\
=& (-2i (\hat{n}\cdot J) \sigma)_j
\end{align*}
where I have used $[\sigma_i, \sigma_j] = 2i \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k$ and $(J_i)_{jk} = -\epsilon_{ijk}$.
So we see, indeed, that
$$
\ad(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)(\sigma) = -2i (\hat{n}\cdot J) \sigma
$$
from which $(1)$ then follows.

The one part of this proof I'm sketchy on is the implication that
$$
\ad(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma))(\sigma) = \theta (\hat{n}\cdot J) \sigma
$$
implies
$$
\exp(\ad(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)))(\sigma) = \exp(\theta (\hat{n}\cdot J)) \sigma
$$
I find it a little funny because on the LHS we have an operator that acts on individual Pauli matrices and on the RHS we have a matrix that multiplies the Pauli matrix vector.
edit: This last implication that I was dubious about is no problem, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4938616/operator-exponential-equality-question-does-x-sigma-y-sigma-imply-expx/4938648#4938648
